# Different background of site opened in fancyBox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

i want to open a page in fancyBox. The page something.php have got black background, but if i open something.php via fancyBox the backkground of page is white. Have you got any idea? I think that all pages opened via fancyBox have got implicitly white background. How can i change background of page into different color.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the way you open *something.php* and it has nothing to do with the overlay color.

If you open *something.php* using `type: "iframe"` then *something.php* will behave as any normal web page with its own layout and css styles. In this case, *something.php* background should be black as expected.

On the other hand, if you open *something.php* via `ajax` (most likely the way you are doing since I don't see any `type` defined in your code)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $(".various").fancybox({ 
  maxWidth   : 1000, 
  maxHeight  : 700, 
  fitToView  : false, 
  width      : '100%', 
  height     : '100%', 
  autoSize   : false, 
  closeClick : false, 
  openEffect : 'none', 
  closeEffect: 'none', 
  overlayColor  : 'black'  //<-- this is NOT a valid option for v2.x
 });
});
```

....then *something.php* will inherit the background color of fancybox (the `.fancybox-skin` selector, which is `#F9F9F9` by default)

If this is the way you intend to open the page, then you have two choices :

1. Set a wrapper container inside *something.php* and set some CSS styles to that wrapper in your main page (from within you launch fancybox)
2. Change the background color of the `.fancybox-skin` within your own CSS file or a CSS inline declaration. If the first, make sure your CSS file is loaded AFTER the fancybox CSS file.

   ```
   .fancybox-skin {
    background-color: #000;
   }
   ```

**EDIT**:

You could combine, for the content background color:

```
.fancybox-inner {
 background-color: #000; /* black */
}
```

... and for the border around the content :

```
.fancybox-skin {
  background-color: #ff0000; /* red */
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But the frame around the content in fancyBox(something.php) is black too. How can i change the color of frame around something.php?

Answer (score -1):

It may change depending on which version of fancyBox you are using. 
But try to set `'overlayColor'`  parameter of fancyBox.

Comment: I am using 2.1.0.0 . I have got this code $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".various").fancybox({
  maxWidth : 1000,
  maxHeight : 700,
  fitToView : false,
  width  : '100%',
  height  : '100%',
  autoSize : false,
  closeClick : false,
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  overlayColor: 'black' but ut doesn't work